# MPAndroidChart Move origin to the bottom where labels are

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have this chart where the origin, that is (0, 0) is above another line. I expected it to be the only line like the second chart. Ho do I remove the bottom line and make the origin the first bottom line?

Here is what I have

[image]

Here is what I want

[image]

**UPDATE**

After applying `xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)` as suggested by @Lilya the chart got improved. Bottom line is gone. But still shows line below 0 on Y-axis and the labels haven't moved yet to where the extra line was. see the image

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried ```xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)```?

Comment: nope. let me try that out

Comment: it definitely takes a step ahead. But Still have Y axis going below 0 and the labels don't go up to fill the space. See updated answer

Comment: Please, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701311/11219710

Comment: thank you. I will take a look of that

Comment: Just tried that. While it moves the axis correctly, it limits min value to 0 so does not work in case of -ve values. Do we have something similar but that allows for -ve values to be plotted correctly